# maven s3 wagon provider

Tags: java, maven-2, amazon-s3

How to deploy with wagon s3 provider?

I've found several plugins, most of them are incomplete, some of them are not maintaned. There is also a sandbox plugin from official maven SVN repository but I'm figuring how to use it.

Any hint?

Comment: There is also some information about S3 wagon providers [on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49737238/mvn-deploy-not-loading-the-s3-credentials/)

Answer (score 13):

There is a newer s3 provider by spring which works:

```
<build>
    <extensions>
        <extension>
            <groupId>org.springframework.build.aws</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.springframework.build.aws.maven</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0.RELEASE</version>
        </extension>
    </extensions>
</build>
```

If you would like to use it with maven 3, you need encrypt you passphrase in your settings.xml.

Step-by-step instructions are [here](https://github.com/SpringSource/aws-maven).

Comment: This extension is now very old and doesn't seem to work any more with the current AWS: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49737238/mvn-deploy-not-loading-the-s3-credentials

Comment: This component is no longer maintained as of Apr 30, 2019.
See https://github.com/spring-attic/aws-maven

Answer (score 13):

[This wagon](https://github.com/jcaddel/maven-s3-wagon/) is what we are using to deploy to S3.  It's similar to Spring's, but has multi-threaded upload support.

This lets the CI server push a lot of Maven content out to S3 very quickly.  (22k files and 400mb's of content in ~50 seconds)

https://github.com/jcaddel/maven-s3-wagon

```
<build>
 <extensions>
   <extension>
    <groupId>org.kuali.maven.wagons</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-s3-wagon</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.1</version>
   </extension>
 </extensions>
</build>
```

Comment: Hi @Jeff Caddel - What if I wanted to pull/download already uploaded jar in my current project from s3 repository?

Comment: This extension is now very old and doesn't seem to work any more with the current AWS: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49737238/mvn-deploy-not-loading-the-s3-credentials

Comment: It doesn't seem to work with existing buckets of other regions. I've tried with other region like "ap-southeast-3" and got "IllegalLocationConstraintException, AWS Error Message: The ap-southeast-3 location constraint is incompatible for the region specific endpoint this request was sent to".

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative:

```
<build>
  <extensions>
    <extension>
      <groupId>org.cyclopsgroup</groupId>
      <artifactId>awss3-maven-wagon</artifactId>
      <version>0.1</version>
    </extension>
  </extensions>
  [...]
</build>
```

Then in `settings.xml`:

```
<servers>
  <server>
    <id>foo.s3</id>
    <username>AKIAJ.......OLVBA</username>
    <password>PsndORui..............KGZtDpeIYjsA/</password>
  </server>
</servers>
```

And then in your `pom.xml`:

```
<distributionManagement>
  <repository>
    <id>foo</id>
    <url>s3://foo.s3/</url>
  </repository>
</distributionManagement>
```

Should work.

Comment: I tried this one but it doesn't seem to set the files to public view like the kuali one does.  I had to go into s3 after the upload to set them manually.

Answer (score 1):

Another option, which is a fork of the jcaddel plugin, was last updated March 2016 but works for me:

```
<extension>
    <groupId>co.axiomzen.maven.wagons</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-s3-wagon</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.6</version>
</extension>
```

Looks like the main weaknesses are: old AWS SDK version, doesn't use the Default AWS Credentials Chain, so lacks support for things like credentials from ECS. Also, characters like "@" and ":" in the URL don't get encoded properly, though I'm not sure if that's a problem with the wagon or with Maven.

Answer (score 1):

I made one that supports AWS SSO (OIDC auth) that uses the second version of the SDK. Maybe it can be useful for you too.

https://github.com/embriq-nordic/aws-oidc-s3-maven-wagon

```
<extension>
    <groupId>io.github.embriq-nordic</groupId>
    <artifactId>aws-oidc-s3-maven-wagon</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.0</version>
</extension>
```

Since it uses the second version of the SDK it uses the credentials provider chain used by that one.