# How exactly do you get a JAR into Maven Central

Tags: java, maven, maven-central

I have built a JAR and want to put it into Maven Central.  How do I actually do that?

I have reviewed the instructions here:

https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-central-repository-upload.html

This has got to be the worst set of instructions I have ever seen.  Seriously, try reading it.

These instructions make no sense to me.  They are basically impossible to understand.  Can someone please share with me a simple plain-English set of steps for how to actually get your JAR into Maven Central?  Would really appreciate it.

Comment: I tried reading it. I was successful in deploying an artifact. This isn't *quite* a rant, but you'll have a lot more success with specific questions.

Comment: Optional, use a *private* repository: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12410423/how-do-i-setup-a-private-remotely-accessible-maven-repository

Comment: Q: Do you (or does your organization) really need to use "Maven Central"?  Or do you just need a "Maven repository", for your project(s)?

Comment: If they are so worst than make suggestions to improve them...https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/MNGSITE/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like explained between the lines on that page, you need a supported repository hosting location to be able to get your artifact into maven central. Since there is only a handful of such locations, the best bet to get something in there is to have it as open source release, as those have an open one:

> The easiest way to upload another project is to use the Open Source
>   Software Repository Hosting (OSSRH), which is an approved repository
>   provided by Sonatype for any OSS Project that want to get their
>   artifacts into Central Repository.

That's what I've used as well. Refer to [their instructions](http://central.sonatype.org/pages/ossrh-guide.html) for details. In short, you need to

- create a jira ticket for your project and get it approved
- deploy your artifact (fulfilling the [requirements](http://central.sonatype.org/pages/requirements.html), using either [Maven](http://central.sonatype.org/pages/apache-maven.html) or [some other deployment tool](http://central.sonatype.org/pages/ossrh-guide.html#deployment)) to their private staging area
- promote the release to release area

If all goes well, after the last step the release will be synced to maven central in roughly ten minutes.