# Maven install a .jar file via direct http:// link

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, teamcity

I have a remote **http://** link which directly downloads a .jar file from a remote server (team city server). I'd like to be able to use this link to download and install this .jar file as a library to a fresh maven project I have created in Intellij.

The guides & solutions I've found show me how to do this manually which works fine in its own way, but I want a remote one for my latest build so that the library keeps up to date with the latest version (if the user desires).

Is this possible?

Comment: Since maven does checks on the signature and sanctity of the downloads, you cannot directly access it and need to have a private maven repository, More details: at the solutions in this query https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12410423/how-do-i-setup-a-private-remotely-accessible-maven-repository

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since maven does checks on the signature and sanctity of the downloads, you cannot directly access the url as you are suggesting and need to have a maven repository, 
More details: at the best maven repository refer this query. [How do I setup a private, remotely accessible Maven repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12410423/how-do-i-setup-a-private-remotely-accessible-maven-repository)

```
<distributionManagement>
<snapshotRepository>
    <id>...</id>
    <url>http:...</url>
</snapshotRepository>
```

You need to essentially use the `install` goal to push the jar to the repository and use the `<repositories>` in the dependent maven projects to point to the hosted maven repository

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>my-internal-site</id>
      <url>http://myserver/repo</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I was worried that was the case. Unfortunately my company is using TeamCity as a build server for the artifacts so I can't jump to a maven repo. I'd ideally like to use maven in the project to get it working since most of my company uses maven, but that doesn't seem to be possible anymore.

Do you have any tips on other types I could use to connect to my private TeamCity server? e.g. Gradle. I'm not familiar with a lot of this.

Comment: Team City can build your application in such a manner that the jar gets deployed into maven repo,  They normally work in tandem. I remember doing this before. Haven't worked much on gradle,