# Maven repository hosting for non-public artifacts?

Tags: maven, repository, hosting, nexus

Is there some hosting solution, be it paid or free, that offers explicit maven repository hosting for non-public artifacts, preferably with support?

These are the alternatives I'm aware about:

- Hosting on your own public server with credentials
- For open source projects, there is [free sonatype hosting](http://www.sonatype.com/people/2009/11/a-year-of-providing-free-maven-repository-hosting/)
- Hosting on [Amazon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/850570/maven-s3-wagon-provider)
- It can be hosted [on github](http://cemerick.com/2010/08/24/hosting-maven-repos-on-github/), [google code](http://www.beeworks.be/hosting-maven-repository-google-code/) or some other VCS hosting

However, all of these either require some maintenance overhead beyond just using the repository manager (beyond just using nexus) and/or are not really fully supported solutions, or are not meant for closed-source projects.

If I need to have a solution that is available on the internet but it is "private" as it should be available for the people of the Company only, are there some other alternatives? I'm assuming here that there is no server that is already public, so having a new server just for maven artifact hosting seems a bit big. I'm a bit surprised that I was unable to find commercial alternatives.

Comment: Vcs and GitHub hosting is just plain wrong. You *need* a repository manager

Comment: What "maintenance overhead" you see in Amazon S3?

Comment: @yegor256 basically, you don't get just a repository manager, but you need to think about the whole server. You are in charge of being up to date with updates, runtime health checks and stuff like that. Amazon can provide tools for it but it is still something that someone has to act on. It's not like they guarantee that a repository manager service is operational, they'll just try to ensure that their end of the bargain (servers etc) work.

Comment: I think you misunderstand how Amazon S3 works. There are no servers, and yes, there is a guarantee of service availability.

Comment: @yegor256 that might be, as I haven't used it. So they'll guarantee that a repo manager will work, and keep it up-to-date with any updates there might be? Would it be a repository manager software there, with UI, or is it just a storage of files, like a VCS solution would?

Comment: S3 is just a storage of objects (not necessarily files). It doesn't know that it's a Maven repository. Your client-side client implements necessary functionality (Maven S3 wagon provider, as explained [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/850570/maven-s3-wagon-provider)).

Comment: Yes, that's in line with how I thought it would be. So basically maintenance overhead would be implementing and maintaining the client-side functionality, and the solution as such is not supported beyond storage - the maven repo usage is not guaranteed to work.

Comment: note to myself: bintray seems to [offer something similar](https://bintray.com/account/pricing)

Comment: Another note: see this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12410423/how-do-i-setup-a-private-remotely-accessible-maven-repository)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Jfrog offer their artifactory repository manager as a cloud service.

Personally some of the default configuration choices ("fixing" metadata, etc) are just plain wrong, but you can configure it to do the right thing.

(Full disclosure: both jfrog and sonatype are partners of cloudbees (my employer))

Edit:
They offer a [30-day trial](https://www.jfrog.com/artifactory/free-trial/#Cloud), and their pricing can be seen [here](https://www.jfrog.com/artifactory/buy-now/#Cloud).

Comment: FWIW, Artifactory OSS is available free of charge.

Comment: https://repsy.io also looks promising.

Comment: Jfrog is on the verge of a service end - https://jfrog.com/blog/into-the-sunset-bintray-jcenter-gocenter-and-chartcenter/

Answer (score 15):

I'm developer of [mymavenrepo.com](https://mymavenrepo.com/) - it's very simple maven hosting which perfectly fits for personal use and small companies

Comment: Looks great. Cheaper than running my own Nexus instance on AWS EC2 like I have been doing.

Comment: like about less configuration on mymavenrepo.com

Comment: @fedor.belov, Registration & login on your site aren't functioning. Clicking Register or Login does nothing. Just rolls the busy icon on the button and does nothing.Perhaps you may want  to check?

Answer (score 5):

[JitPack](http://jitpack.io/private) is a services that makes it easy to host non-public (private) Maven artifacts.

The way it works is that it builds your private Git repositories from source and publishes resulting artifacts. 
The artifacts are only accessible to you and those who have access to Git repo itself, like people in your company.

The way you use it is by adding the repository and point your dependencies at the Git Repo:

1. Add repository:

```xml
<repository>
    <id>jitpack.io</id>
    <url>https://jitpack.io</url>
</repository>
```

2. Add dependency

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.User</groupId>
    <artifactId>Repository</artifactId>
    <version>Tag</version>
</dependency>
```

More information and authentication in the [docs](https://jitpack.io/docs/PRIVATE/). Their pricing can be seen on their [pricing page](https://jitpack.io/private#subscribe).

Answer (score 2):

I've been searching for this as well and came acrosss this link https://blog.openshift.com/nexus-repository-manager-in-the-cloud-for-free-with-openshift/ which explains how to set up a Nexus application on OpenShift.  I followed the steps outlined in this page and got it up and running pretty quickly.  You can disble the "anonymous" user to remove public access and set up your own users.  It can tie into LDAP you have that available.

Comment: This isn't with explicit support for it though.

Answer (score 2):

It seems there is a service called [deps](https://www.deps.co) about to open in 2017. From their description, it sounds like the answer to my question, but we'll have to see how it turns out.

Answer (score 2):

This might be considered a promotion, but we just released support for hosting Maven repositories in the cloud at Deveo. There is no other information available yet than the release [blog post](http://blog.deveo.com/whats-new-in-deveo-3-17/). The pricing, however, should be more friendly than what jFrog offers.

Disclaimer: I'm affiliated with the company.

Comment: Nice, and about the " $75/month for the min service" stated above, here it looks more like free until 1GB and then 1€/GB/month.

Answer (score 1):

There is no commercial offering of Nexus Repository in the cloud as such, but any managed server that includes the features to run a Java application is suitable. And there are LOTS of them around. And others partners like CA automatically include it in a stack they provision for customers.

The only overhead you are going to have to manage is to install and run Nexus Repository. That however is trivial and can be done within a couple of minutes.

Depending on your usage you could even run this on a VM that you turn off when no one needs it. E.g. out of 24 hours a day .. if your dev and  CI servers only need it for 12 .. shut the VM down the rest of the time. And you can automate that all easily as well.

Comment: I disagree on effort being trivial - it might be for installation, but not for continuous maintenance. I think this question is looking for managed solutions with enterprise support.

Comment: Nexus Repository is very hands off and low maintenance once installed and if you get a Pro license you have full support for Sonatype for whatever youtinstallation is. Cloud or not or a mixture. A license gives you the ability to run as many installations as you want.

Comment: Have to add that in my current project, we've now been without builds for several weeks since nexus metadata updates are broken and our in-house support says they are unable to fix it. This hilights the point that it needs proper support.

Answer (score -2):

DropBox is another possible option see https://code.google.com/p/peter-lavalle/wiki/MavenOnDropBox

Comment: the instructions refer to using dropbox as a public repo, where all artifacts would be visible for the world. With this question I was looking for hosting for non-public artifacts, and preferrably with support.

Comment: The question does specifically refer to "non-public artifacts" with support