# mvn deploy not loading the S3 credentials

Tags: maven, amazon-s3

I'm converting a Gradle project to Maven and one of the things I'm doing is deploying the Jar to S3. I've configured the distribution like this:

```
<distributionManagement>
    <repository>
        <id>aws-release</id>
        <name>AWS Release Repository</name>
        <url>s3://projectx-support/maven2/release</url>
    </repository>
    <snapshotRepository>
        <id>aws-snapshots</id>
        <name>AWS Snapshot Repository</name>
        <url>s3://projectx-support/maven2/snapshots</url>
    </snapshotRepository>
</distributionManagement>
```

and I've tried with:

```
<extensions>
    <extension>
        <groupId>org.springframework.build</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-maven</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    </extension>
</extensions>
```

and

```
<extensions>
    <extension>
        <groupId>org.kuali.maven.wagons</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-s3-wagon</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.1</version>
    </extension>
</extensions>
```

and in both cases I get the same error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy (default-deploy) on project projectxcommon: Failed to retrieve remote metadata tech.projectx:projectxcommon:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml: Could not transfer metadata tech.projectx:projectxcommon:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml from/to aws-snapshots (s3://projectx-support/maven2/snapshots): Unable to load AWS credentials from any provider in the chain -> [Help 1]
```

When running in debug mode, these are the warnings/errors:

```
[DEBUG] Configuration override awssdk_config_override.json not found.
[DEBUG] Unable to load credentials from EnvironmentVariableCredentialsProvider: Unable to load AWS credentials from environment variables (AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID (or AWS_ACCESS_KEY) and AWS_SECRET_KEY (or AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY))
[DEBUG] Unable to load credentials from SystemPropertiesCredentialsProvider: Unable to load AWS credentials from Java system properties (aws.accessKeyId and aws.secretKey)
[DEBUG] Connecting to EC2 instance metadata service at URL: http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/iam/security-credentials/
[DEBUG] Unable to load credentials from InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider: Unable to load credentials from Amazon EC2 metadata service
[DEBUG] Unable to load credentials from org.springframework.build.aws.maven.AuthenticationInfoAWSCredentialsProvider@19ed4e8: null
[WARNING] Could not transfer metadata tech.projectx:projectxcommon:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml from/to aws-snapshots (s3://projectx-support/maven2/snapshots): Unable to load AWS credentials from any provider in the chain
```

When running with `-e` this is the stack trace:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy (default-deploy) on project projectxcommon: Failed to retrieve remote metadata tech.projectx:projectxcommon:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml: Could not transfer metadata tech.projectx:projectxcommon:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml from/to aws-snapshots (s3://projectx-
support/maven2/snapshots): Unable to load AWS credentials from any provider in the chain -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy (default-deploy) on project projectxcommon: Failed to retrieve remote metadata tech.projectx:projectxcommon:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml: Could not transfer metadata tech.projectx:projectxcommon:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-m
etadata.xml from/to aws-snapshots (s3://projectx-support/maven2/snapshots): Unable to load AWS credentials from any provider in the chain
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:213)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:290)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:194)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Failed to retrieve remote metadata tech.projectx:projectxcommon:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml: Could not transfer metadata tech.projectx:projectxcommon:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml from/to aws-snapshots (s3://projectx-support/maven2/snapshots): Unable to load AWS credentials from any prov
ider in the chain
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.deploy.DeployMojo.execute (DeployMojo.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:208)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:290)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:194)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.artifact.deployer.ArtifactDeploymentException: Failed to retrieve remote metadata tech.projectx:projectxcommon:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml: Could not transfer metadata tech.projectx:projectxcommon:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml from/to aws-snapshots (s3://projectx-support/maven2/snapshots): Unable to load AWS credentia
ls from any provider in the chain
    at org.apache.maven.artifact.deployer.DefaultArtifactDeployer.deploy (DefaultArtifactDeployer.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.deploy.AbstractDeployMojo.deploy (AbstractDeployMojo.java:167)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.deploy.DeployMojo.execute (DeployMojo.java:157)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:208)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:290)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:194)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.deployment.DeploymentException: Failed to retrieve remote metadata tech.projectx:projectxcommon:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml: Could not transfer metadata tech.projectx:projectxcommon:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml from/to aws-snapshots (s3://projectx-support/maven2/snapshots): Unable to load AWS credentials from any p
rovider in the chain
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDeployer.upload (DefaultDeployer.java:425)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDeployer.deploy (DefaultDeployer.java:268)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDeployer.deploy (DefaultDeployer.java:223)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.deploy (DefaultRepositorySystem.java:384)
    at org.apache.maven.artifact.deployer.DefaultArtifactDeployer.deploy (DefaultArtifactDeployer.java:142)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.deploy.AbstractDeployMojo.deploy (AbstractDeployMojo.java:167)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.deploy.DeployMojo.execute (DeployMojo.java:157)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:208)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:290)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:194)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.transfer.MetadataTransferException: Could not transfer metadata tech.projectx:projectxcommon:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml from/to aws-snapshots (s3://projectx-support/maven2/snapshots): Unable to load AWS credentials from any provider in the chain
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.MetadataTransportListener.transferFailed (MetadataTransportListener.java:52)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$TaskRunner.run (BasicRepositoryConnector.java:365)
    at org.eclipse.aether.util.concurrency.RunnableErrorForwarder$1.run (RunnableErrorForwarder.java:75)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$DirectExecutor.execute (BasicRepositoryConnector.java:583)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector.get (BasicRepositoryConnector.java:232)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDeployer.upload (DefaultDeployer.java:395)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDeployer.deploy (DefaultDeployer.java:268)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDeployer.deploy (DefaultDeployer.java:223)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.deploy (DefaultRepositorySystem.java:384)
    at org.apache.maven.artifact.deployer.DefaultArtifactDeployer.deploy (DefaultArtifactDeployer.java:142)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.deploy.AbstractDeployMojo.deploy (AbstractDeployMojo.java:167)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.deploy.DeployMojo.execute (DeployMojo.java:157)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:208)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:290)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:194)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: com.amazonaws.AmazonClientException: Unable to load AWS credentials from any provider in the chain
    at com.amazonaws.auth.AWSCredentialsProviderChain.getCredentials (AWSCredentialsProviderChain.java:117)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke (AmazonS3Client.java:3377)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke (AmazonS3Client.java:3336)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.getBucketLocation (AmazonS3Client.java:669)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.getBucketLocation (AmazonS3Client.java:677)
    at org.springframework.build.aws.maven.SimpleStorageServiceWagon.connectToRepository (SimpleStorageServiceWagon.java:86)
    at org.springframework.build.aws.maven.AbstractWagon.connect (AbstractWagon.java:146)
    at org.eclipse.aether.transport.wagon.WagonTransporter.connectWagon (WagonTransporter.java:342)
    at org.eclipse.aether.transport.wagon.WagonTransporter.pollWagon (WagonTransporter.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.aether.transport.wagon.WagonTransporter.execute (WagonTransporter.java:431)
    at org.eclipse.aether.transport.wagon.WagonTransporter.get (WagonTransporter.java:412)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$GetTaskRunner.runTask (BasicRepositoryConnector.java:453)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$TaskRunner.run (BasicRepositoryConnector.java:360)
    at org.eclipse.aether.util.concurrency.RunnableErrorForwarder$1.run (RunnableErrorForwarder.java:75)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$DirectExecutor.execute (BasicRepositoryConnector.java:583)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector.get (BasicRepositoryConnector.java:232)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDeployer.upload (DefaultDeployer.java:395)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDeployer.deploy (DefaultDeployer.java:268)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDeployer.deploy (DefaultDeployer.java:223)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.deploy (DefaultRepositorySystem.java:384)
    at org.apache.maven.artifact.deployer.DefaultArtifactDeployer.deploy (DefaultArtifactDeployer.java:142)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.deploy.AbstractDeployMojo.deploy (AbstractDeployMojo.java:167)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.deploy.DeployMojo.execute (DeployMojo.java:157)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:208)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:290)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:194)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
```

The credentials are correct and defined on `~/.m2/settings.xml`:

```
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
    <servers>
        <server>
            <id>aws-release</id>
            <username>...</username>
            <password>...</password>
        </server>
        <server>
            <id>aws-snapshot</id>
            <username>...</username>
            <password>...</password>
        </server>
    </servers>
</settings>
```

and indeed, the Gradle plugin was successfully deploying configured like this:

```
publishing {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url "s3://projectx-support/maven2"
            credentials(AwsCredentials) {
                try {
                    def defaultCredentials = new com.amazonaws.auth.DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain().getCredentials()
                    accessKey defaultCredentials.getAWSAccessKeyId()
                    secretKey defaultCredentials.getAWSSecretKey()
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    // Nevermind
                }
            }
        }
    }

    publications {
        mavenJava(MavenPublication) {
            from components.java
        }
    }
}
```

What am I missing? what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 9):

Well, I found the problem: Those two plugins are horribly old, obsolete and abandoned.

```
<extension>
   <groupId>com.allogy.maven.wagon</groupId>
   <artifactId>maven-s3-wagon</artifactId>
   <version>1.2.0</version>
</extension>
```

seems to work, but I'm not sure if that's the best one to use.

Comment: This is the only maven s3 wagon working out there for me

Comment: I've taken the liberty of bumping the version number in your answer to 1.2 - as of 2020 that solves the dependency issue for me with J9+ without resorting to the "plugin with extensions" approach.

Comment: I want to fetch/download the dependencies that already in S3 when I build my project. Can I use this wagon for that task

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, don't have the reputation to comment on the existing answer. This is an addendum.  If you want to use the allogy wagon to upload to S3, and you're using a more recent JDK (I'm using OpenJDK 11.0.3), then you get tripped up by Jaxb being removed from the JDK in J 9.

I was using the `<extension>` approach above in my pom and really struggled to add Jaxb dependencies in such a way that the wagon extension would pick it up.  The solution is to make it a `<plugin>` that has `<extensions>true</>`, as you can then add dependencies.

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>com.allogy.maven.wagon</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-s3-wagon</artifactId>
  <version>1.1.0</version>
  <extensions>true</extensions>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
      <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
      <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
      <version>2.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

Comment: The latest version `1.2.0` now means this approach isn't required, but thanks anyway, this certainly got me there!